# Error setting .files of file input tag in IE

Tags: javascript, file, internet-explorer, input, bulma

I'm trying to inject html elements (specifically file input elements) into a parent div when selecting a file from one specific input. When this input selects a file, it is supposed to passed that file on to the input element I am creating.

Main input selecting file:

```
var file = document.getElementById("file");
file.onchange = function(){
    var ext = this.value.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/);
    if(ext!=null && ext.length>1){
        switch (ext[1].toLowerCase()) {
            case 'doc':
            ...
                if (file.files.length > 0) {
                    appendFile(file.files);
                }
                break;
            default:
                alert('Sorry, files of type .' + ext[1].toLowerCase() + " are not allowed.");
                this.value = '';
        }
    }
};
```

if there is a file onchange, pass file into appendFile

```
function appendFile(files){
    ...
    if(files.length>0){
        file = files[0];
        ...
        htmlFile.appendChild(createFileInput(files));
        ...
        parentDiv.append(htmlFile);
    }
}
```

do an extra check to make sure file exists, generate other htmlElements and pass the files in to the createFileInput function to create the input tag

```
function createFileInput(files){
    fileInput = document.createElement("input");
    fileInput.setAttribute('type','file');
    fileInput.files=files;
    fileInput.classList.add('files');
    fileInput.style.display = 'none';
    return fileInput;
}
```

creates an input tag of type file, and sets the files in the input equal to the files passed into the function.

This works perfectly for me in Chrome. It doesn't work correctly for me in IE, but I'm pretty sure I have tracked down the error to the `fileInput.files=files;` line in the `createFileInput()` method.

For some reason the files field of these hidden inputs do not get set in IE. Does anyone know why this is, or know of a different way to set the files field of an input?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just including a hidden `<input>` tag and triggering a click on that input to take in the files. After taking in the file for that tag, i generated a new `<input>` tag which I then triggered for the next time a user clicked to import a file. I just continued this process until the user was done importing files

Essentially I changed my code to this

```
function triggerFileClick(){
    var files = document.getElementsByClassName('files');
    var file = files[files.length-1];
    file.onchange = function(){
        var ext = this.value.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/);
        if(ext!=null && ext.length>1){
            switch (ext[1].toLowerCase()) {
                case 'doc':
                ...
                    if (file.files.length > 0) {
                        appendFile(file.files);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    alert('Sorry, files of type .' + ext[1].toLowerCase() + " are not allowed.");
                    this.value = '';
            }
        }
    };
    file.click();
}
```

When a user clicks on the file import button, it triggers this function. Since I already have one `<input>` tag (with class 'files') in the html, it triggers a click on that file. The onchange for that file then runs my `appendFile()` function which in turn inserts another `<input>` tag with class 'files' into the dom. So the next time the add files button is clicked, it triggers a click on that newly added `<input>` tag.